# How to convert arguments into an object

Tags: javascript

In the following:

```
const s1 = "HEllo Rick, it's Tom calling."
const r1 = /\b(?<capital>[A-Z])([a-z])/g;
let rp = s1.replace(r1, ({obj}) => console.log(obj));
```

How would I get all the args from [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) into a single object here?

Answer (score -1):

The syntax would be:

```js
const s1 = "HEllo Rick, it's Tom calling."
const r1 = /\b(?<capital>[A-Z])([a-z])/g;
let rp = s1.replace(r1, (...obj) => console.log(obj));
```